# Why is program not found in PATH

Tags: bash, path

I've installed `ipython` inside virtualenv on my macOS. My PATH environment variable also shows virtualenv path to be at the beginning. `which` command also shows that `ipython` at the correct location.

The problem is, when I run `ipython`, the shell is finding the previous installation in an odd place. Here's some examples:

```
(csv_import) $ ipython
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
(csv_import) $ 
(csv_import) $ which ipython
/Users/zeinep/.virtualenvs/csv_import/bin/ipython
(csv_import) $ 
(csv_import) $ echo $PATH
/Users/zeinep/.virtualenvs/csv_import/bin:/Users/zeinep/.avn/bin:/Users/zeinep/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/bin:/Users/zeinep/Library/Python/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
(csv_import) $ 
(csv_import) $ 
(csv_import) $ /Users/zeinep/.virtualenvs/csv_import/bin/ipython
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:13:06) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
In [1]:
```

As can be seen, if I use a full path, it works. Otherwise, old installation at `/usr/local/bin/ipython` is run even though the shell should be finding the one in in virtualenv as far as I can see.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is that macOS?

Comment: @terdon yes, this is macOS

Comment: OK. If you've installed in in a virtualenv, why are you trying to run it outside the virtualenv? Does it work of you do `. /Users/zeinep/.virtualenvs/csv_import/bin/activate` (or whatever the right command is to activate the virtualenv) and then run `ipython`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller it seems like that solved it! Thanks!

Comment: @terdon it's inside virtualenv. That `(csv_import)` at the beginning is telling me I'm inside the virtual env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently added `/Users/zeinep/.virtualenvs/csv_import/bin` to your `$PATH` after bash had saved (hashed) the `/usr/local/bin` version. The fix is as simple as `hash -d ipython`.